# YouTube Data API - Can you get comments from a channel's discussion page?

Tags: youtube-api

Does the YouTube Data API allow you to get comments left on a channel's discussion page? I'm able to get comments left on videos, but can't figure out how to pull in comments left for the channel itself.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list

This API can be used to access comments left on videos and **channels**.

Lazykh is looking for other solutions. Keep a lookout on this video for more info, if you are still interested:
https://youtu.be/NjDZvCI6WBM

Comment: Unfortunately, @Gael, your post does not answer the OP's question: the [`CommentThreads.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) API endpoint **does not provide the comments posted on a channel's *Community Tab***.

Comment: The OP asked for the "Discussion" tab, not the "Community" tab. The API returns the post associated with the "Discussion" tab, even after it has been replaced with the "Community" tab. The API the OP is looking for if the "list (by channel ID)"
Use cases:
- list (by video ID)
- list (by channel ID)
- list (all threads related to channel ID)

Comment: See the video at the end of my post for distinction between the "Discussion" tab and the "Community" tab